# How to apply global MAX() in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig Scripting

I have a dataset as follows:

```
 name  | age
-------+----
Ashis  | 60
Arun   | 22
Nirmal | 48
Ram    | 67
Amar   | 35
```

How can I get the record with maximum age using Pig Scripting?

My Output should be

```
Ram,67
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your data in descending order by age and limit your data by 1 to get the record with max age. Like so:

```
inputData = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (name:charray, age:long);
sortedInput = ORGER inputData BY age DESC;
topRecord = LIMIT sortedInput 1;
DUMP topRecord;
```

It is worth mentioning that this is not an operation suited for map-reduce (through pig here) since both ORDER and LIMIT don't make use of parallelism and your job will be bottle-necked by a single reducer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Can we directly get the the o/p by applying MAX() ?

Comment: If you cared about just getting the max age, you could do something like maxAge = FOREACH (GROUP inputData ALL) GENERATE MAX(inputData.age); But if you need to retain other fields in the record corresponding to max age (like the name in your case), you will have to follow the way mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel that this has answered your question, you can mark it as such.